# Is it safe to type a password in a VNC client connected to a server to access another server?

Tags: passwords, vnc

I am using VNC GUI client from my Desktop to connect to a remote (ubuntu) server, say S1. From the remote server (S1), I will be logging into another server (say S2) via SSH. Via VNC client, I will be typing in the SSH password of S2 on putty running on S1 to gain access to S2. Is this a safe way of doing things?

Comment: Safe against what? Who owns S1? Is the VNC connection encrypted?

Comment: Both S1 and S2 are dedicated servers hosted with different hosting providers (both the providers have a good reputation).  The incoming VNC traffic to S1 from several IPs (of Office, staff homes) is allowed. But the VNC connection is not encrypted. S2 is open only to incoming SSH from S1.  I am worried about typing in SSH root password to gain access to S2 from a VNC session on S1. Can the VNC connection be intercepted in some way and the passwords be compromised?

Comment: If the VNC connection is not encrypted, anyone on its path can capture and inspect the traffic.

Comment: In that case, I guess something like running VNC through SSH tunnel should help. Kindly let me know your views on the same, probably as an answer, so that I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VNC connection is not encrypted, anyone on its path can capture and inspect the traffic. VNC uses the RFB Protocol (Remote Frame Buffer), and Wireshark, for example, already have dissectors for it, so don't count on it.

Some VNC solutions have proprietary plugins that add security (UltraVNC is one of those), but you don't need that. If you use a SSH tunnel to access S1, all traffic will be protected by SSH's encryption.

And I have way more trust on SSH doing encryption than a VNC solution.